# How can I capitalize a single letter after a certain character?

Tags: bash, sed

I have some strings

```
some-string
some-other-string
yet-another-string-to-handle
```

I want to convert those strings into

```
someString
someOtherString
yetAnotherStringToHandle
```

I'm trying to do the following

```
echo yet-another-string-to-handle | sed -r 's/\-(.*)/\U\1\E/g'
```

But that results in

```
yetANOTHER-STRING-TO-HANDLE
```

Needless to say, I'm a bit lost. Any suggestions on how I can achieve my goal?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With GNU sed:

```
sed -E 's/-(.)/\u\1/g' file
```

> `\u`: Turn the next character to uppercase (GNU 'sed' extension).

Output:

```
someString
someOtherString
yetAnotherStringToHandle
```

---

See: `info sed`